# Create a bash program that lists only files that were modified in the last year

Tags: bash

I want to create a bash program that lists only files that were modified in the last year.

> Hint: the `-l` output of ls will be helpful

This is from my class exercise but I don't know how to start. Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Recommended reading for your teacher and yourself: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, you can create a file dated last year with `touch` command:

```
touch oldFile -d "Mar 9 2017"
```

Then you can use `grep` and `date` commands as follows:

```
ls -l -1 | grep "$(date "+%Y" --date="1 year ago")"
```

where `date "+%Y" --date="1 year ago"` will expand into the previous year, that is `2017`. Result:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 userX userX    0 Mar  9  2017 oldFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Cyrus' link of not parsing `ls` output, I suggest using:

```
find . -type f -newermt 2017-01-01 ! -newermt 2017-12-31 -ls
```

Not `-l`, but `-ls`.

Or, to get a real answer to the question that also works next year:

```
#!/bin/bash
last_year=$(date +%Y -d "1 year ago")
yearstart=$(date  +%Y-%m-%d -d "1 january")
find . -type f -newermt $last_year-01-01 ! -newermt $yearstart -ls
```